# Simply count values using Pivot Tables in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-pivot

Sorry to have maybe simple question, but I just learning pivot tables and some advanced functions in the Excel.

Let's imagine we having a table with Movies and Votes followed by User1 and User2 and their votes. Please see below table.

User1's votes: 4 and 5.8
User2's votes: 7 and 5.8
So, the common vote is 5.8.

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| Vote   | User1 | User2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Movie1 |   4.0 |   7.0 |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Movie2 |   5.8 |   5.8 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to use Pivot Tables to transform and count votes by vote number. Expected result:

```
+--------+-------+
| Vote   | Count |
+--------+-------+
|    4.0 |     1 |
+--------+-------+
|    5.8 |     2 |
+--------+-------+
|      7 |     1 |
+--------+-------+
```

Is it possible to do this in Excel using Pivot Tables?

Thank you.

Comment: What's Vote = 7 and Count = 1? Is that a third movie or is it supposed to be some subgrouping (i.e. Subtotal)?

Comment: @Wizhi, Vote=7 and Count=1, means we have one movie votes for seven, and two movies votes for 5.8, etc.